# Can't edit a question after reviewing 20 posts

Tags: discussion

I was going through a few new questions to see if I could improve a few; however, I am not allowed to after I went through 20 suggested edits earlier.

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 15 hours to continue reviewing.

Comment: was there a pending edit on the question? otherwise you _can edit_

Comment: There was a pending edit. Why can I not see the edit then?

Comment: ^ found a dupe after answering :|

Comment: @SurajRao The magic of SO search engine "mmm, this ? No idea what you're talking about" -> answer ->  "Ohhh,  **that**, yeah sure I remember. Here's your related question".

Comment: @Pac0 used google with `site: meta.stackoverflow.com` to look for OP's comment below my answer.:p

Answer (score 2):

> There was a pending edit. Why can I not see the edit then?

Clicking on edit when there is a pending *suggested* edit takes you (above 2k rep) to the review suggested edit page to allow you to approve/reject or make changes to the edit. It counts as a review action.

Since you have already reached the review limit, it does not show the review page and shows you the message.

You will have to wait till the pending edit passes through the review queue.

Comment: Why not show me the review anyway? Disable the buttons and display the message? Why hide that information

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski if you want something like that, you will have to probably raise a feature request.. not sure if it will be that useful

Comment: Also suggest reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171129/helpless-after-exhausting-daily-limit-for-reviewing-suggested-edits